# Initial code safe

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I´m developing an App with encrypted data. I download the key from my server, but I want get the key encrypted too. For this, I need create a first key in my iOS app and then, decrypt the new Key and save it in the Keychain. Can I have a initial code in a safe way by default? For example, an String, a Key...

Thank you very much,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a key compiled in the binary is not perfectly safe, but it's probably good enough unless your app is a target.

There is no way to hand someone a key without them being able to use it.  It's logically impossible.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Probably I have to create a private Key with a own logarithm in my app.